# express static folder with catchall route

Tags: express

I'm building an angularJS app using the MEAN stack. I want to create a catchall route, that always redirects to my index.html file, but I also want to serve some dependencies I installed locally with bower.

With my current configuration, the express app will return all the public files as html, so my javascript dependencies don't work. If I add `app.use(express.static('public'));`, the catchall route stops working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my server.js:

```
var config = require('./config');

//app configuration
    // body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //CORS requests
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
        next();
    });
    //log all requests to console
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    //db
    mongoose.connect(config.database);

//API routes
    var apiRoutes = require('./app/routes/api')(app, express);
    //register our routes
    app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.use(express.static('public'));

//catchall route
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
});

//start the server
app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Running on: ' + config.port);
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting the public files at '/public' and appending a '/' to the catch-all route.

The following is what I've used in the past

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// ... all other routes

//catch-all-else route
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html'));
});
```